# puppeter AWS lambada stuck on newPage method

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I have a Puppeteer project that runs in AWS lambda, and since yesterday it stopped working. I have made a small change in my code, but it always gets stuck at the browser newPage method,  even after I reverted my changes.

I am using the lambda starter kit project:
https://github.com/sambaiz/puppeteer-lambda-starter-kit
I even tired to upload this project with the default example(which worked for me in the past) without any changes just for test but again it gets stuck at the newPage method, which is very odd.

I suspect that it might be the launch option flags because I saw this post that describes a problem similar to mine:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1523
but the suggested flags are enabled by default by the lambada starter kit:
   '--no-sandbox',
   '--disable-gpu',
   '--single-process',
does anyone have a clue what can be the problem? can anyone recommend any other method to run it Puppeteer on top of AWS lambada?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to solve it.
It works well using lambda layer that contains the chromium.
Here is a nice example:
https://github.com/RafalWilinski/serverless-puppeteer-layers